# MVC .. should one database_model contain CRUD for all object_models? Active record vs. registry pattern

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm writing a fairly simple "fact database" in PHP (with Codeigniter .. but I am trying to get away from the framework internals for learning purposes), and trying to better my MVC/OOP practices.

Previously I would have done this: a fact model, a user model, a source model .. and inside each of those models I would place the CRUD logic for each.  So it would look like this..

```
$this->fact_model->save($fact);
$this->user_model->deactivate($uid);
$this->source_model->get_id($sid);
```

But after reading more, it seems to make sense to have a separate persistence model (ie 'database_model').  But then it seems it would have to contain a full range of CRUD for each type of object, which seems wasteful to me.  I guess I'm looking for how to go to this...

```
$this->db_m->save(Fact $fact);
$this->db_m->update(User $user);
// .. etc .. but also ..
$this->db_m->get_user_id($uid);
// .. and ..
$htis->db_m->get_all_facts();
```

Is this heading in the right direction?  Do I just end up testing for type inside the database model and switching when I need to?  Or do I extend the database model for each type of object?

```
$this->fact_db_m->save(Fact $fact);
$this->fact_db_m->get_all();
$this->source_db_m->get_id($sid);
```

Or something like this, which I guess is the closest to CIs AR implementation.

```
$this->db_m->save('facts', Fact $fact);
$this->db_m->get('user', array('id'=>$uid));
```

I guess this is a case of "active record vs repository".  I understand that repository is easier to test, and the CRUD logic is separate from the object data, and that separation makes sense to me.  But still.. it means you have to write a separate repository model for each entity.  Is this right?

BTW - I know Codeigniter has a Database class and uses active record, and in a way I am just kind of re-creating it with some of those approaches.  I'm just trying to understand things without relying on the framework internals.  Any comments?  Is it just a matter of choice?

Comment: CodeIgniter has nothing to do with MVC design pattern or even OOP paradigm.

Comment: @tereško please stop posting this incorrect information on every CodeIgniter post that asks about MVC. Like it or not, MVC does have something to do with CodeIgniter. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/217152/

Comment: @stormdrain Even in a forum you linked to (http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/217152), we see the following: "So there is an issue, which is not specific to CI, but to any stateless environment." Can we gain some useful principles from MVC? Certainly, but traditional MVC is not possible over HTTP and by extension is not possible in CodeIgniter.

Comment: @stormdrain since you were so nice to link to both CI misinterpretation and wikipedia article, please be so nice and actually **read them**.

Comment: @tereško I did, thank you very much. All else aside, the fact that there is a section in the User Guide and the fact that there are similarities means that there is an association between CI and MVC.

Comment: @LeviMorrison and two lines below your quote: "But I wouldn’t be to worried about that. CI uses a Model, a View and a Controller, and therefore uses MVC. I don’t think the docs refer to this as Fowlers MVC pattern, so it’s a matter of a difference in what exactly the three letters stand for…". I think the fact that there is a section in the user guide, and the quote above make it clear that there is an association between CI and MVC. That's all I'm saying -- there *is* an association.

Comment: @stormdrain If your model, view or controller is not the same as Fowler's M, V or C as in MVC, *then you can't say you are using MVC*.

Comment: @LeviMorrison welp I suppose I missed that directive in the Web Developer Bylaws. What do you propose as an appropriate description of separation of concerns w/r/t CI's model, view, controller structure? Edit: sorry for getting so o/t on this. I see a relationship, you guys don't. Fin.

Comment: So, basically your argument boils down to: "it says in user guide that it is MVC, therefore it must be true". And since user-guide is an unquestionable source of truth, there is no need for you to actually read anything else. It must be awesome feeling to have found this source of boundless truth. Instead of having to read various materials from Beck, Cunningham, Fowler, Evans and all the others. What you are assuming is that if someone has folders "model", "view" and "controller" that it auto-magically means that it is implementing MVC. It doesn't work this way.

Comment: @tereško what I'm saying is that, based on 1) the user guide (which was put out by the people that developed CI); 2) CI's folder structure; 3) the countless references to MVC + CI, to say "CI has nothing to do with MVC" is incorrect. Maybe it should be called something else. Maybe it's patently incorrect. The fact of the matter is that the two are linked. Since it's clear you won't stop, maybe next time include some references when lambasting someone for linking the two. Also: no reason to be so incredibly rude. It's weak and immediately detracts from any point you may have.

Comment: I already named 4 different authors and recommended you to carefully read the wikipedia article. Since you obviously have no intention or doing **any** research, this all is pointless. Ya know what is the connection between CodeIgniter and MVC? Marketing. That horrible framework gets advertised as "mvc framework" and witless noobs blindly swallow that lie. Congratulation - you are one of them.

Comment: @tereško OP here. I looked over some of your posts and it seems I am pursuing MVP, as opposed to MVC. Saying one has nothing do do with another seems harsh. Like "Latvia and Lithuania have nothing to do with each other". Is it fair to say the nucleus of MVC is separation of responsibility?  My first introduction to that was CI, and that knowledge has translated to my other witless nooby experimentation with js.backbone.  Wordpress has *nothing to do* with MVC.  CI does .. a bit.  As for OOP, I wasn't calling CI OOP.  But I can implement OOP in it.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do a little research on my own, thanks to your question, I came across this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx , which explains the differences between different data access patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understood the question correctly, but here goes.

My approach would be to use the separation of models, however the one twist i usually do. i will try to be clear.

Lets say my application is going to require 3 unique features. One for users, facts, sources, All of these models might need to use some common functions like SAVE or LOAD, or UPDATE, or DELETE. Instead of duplicating the common functions into each model, i would simply make a base class with all the common functions, a nd have the base class extend the CI_Model, then all my new model files ( users,facts,sources ) i would have extend my common class.

To better illustrate this, i will throw  some basic code up

**db_common_model Common Class (db_common_model.php)**

```
  class db_common_model extends CI_Model
  {
    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
    * All Common Functions Here */    
    public function save()
    {
      // Do stuff
    }    
    public function update()
    {
      // Do stuff 
    }    
    public function etc()
    {
      // Do stuff
    }
  }
```

**users_model Class (db_common_model.php)**

```
  class users_model extends db_common_model
  {
    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
    * user specific functions */    
    public function get_one()
    {
      // Do stuff
    }    
    public function get_all()
    {
      // Do stuff 
    }    
    public function get_latest()
    {
      // Do stuff
    }    
    public function etc()
    {
      // Do stuff
    }
  }

  /**
  * When using it in CI Controller
  */

  $this->user_model->get_one(); // loads user specific function
  $this->user_model->save(); // Calls all inherited methods from parent db_common_model
  // Etc
```

This way of setting up your models allows you expand common features in the db_common_model, that are automatically available to all children classes.

This allows for clean organization, and allows you to not have to re-invent your common functions in every model.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  That helped.  But I suppose it is mostly a matter of taste, huh.  But I like your approach.